# How to continuously listen to changes in firebase and stop when user logout

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

My actual is "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
" and since it is asked previously too so I changed the question. And I'm not able to understand its proper implementation in context of my code:

My previous code was like this:

```
this.afdb.list('/all-users/' + this.userid + '/all-notifications/',
    ref => ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('pending')).
    valueChanges().subscribe( (data) => {
        this.userAllNotifications = data;
        data.forEach( (item: any) => {
            if (item.status === 'pending') {
                // some code....
            } 
        });
    });
```

But I don't know how to use "ref.off()" in this code. After reading some docs I decided to implement it as shown below:

```
const refNotify = firebase.database().ref('/all-users/' + this.userid + '/all-notifications/')
                                        .orderByChild('status').equalTo('pending');
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
         refNotify.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            this.userAllNotifications = snapshot.val();
        });
    } else {
        refNotify.off();
    }
```

It throws the error "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
" for "this.userAllNotifications".

I tried to change it like this:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
         refNotify.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            this.userAllNotifications = [];
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              this.userAllNotifications.push(childSnapshot.val());
            });
        });
    } else {
        refNotify.off();
    }
```

But then it shows the following error for "childSnapshot" --

`Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

I'm not able to figure out how to implement it properly but
trying to implement the code that can:

1. continuously listen to the new notifications
2. and closes the ref listener if the user is logged out.

In the html, my code is something like this:

`<li *ngFor="let notify of userAllNotifications" (click)="notifiesViewed(notify)">`

Answer (score 0):

So, I come up with this solution:

```
this.userAllNotifications = this.notifyService.getUserNotications(this.userid);
    this.subscriptionNotifies = this.userAllNotifications.subscribe( (data) => {
        data.forEach( (item: any) => {
            // some other code..                
        });
    });
```

Then I unsubscribed the "subscriptionNotifies" in ngOnDestroy() -

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptionNotifies.unsubscribe();
}
```

So, everytime when I navigate to a different route or sign-out, the observable is unsubscribed.